# How do I use data tables in Spock when result is complex?

Tags: groovy, spock

E.g., if I write the following code:

```
expect:
methodToTest(from, to) == result
where:
from          | to            | result
1508446800000 | 1509483600000 | (Entry) [1506805200000L, 1512075600000L]
```

where `methodToTest(long from, long to)` returns an `Entry`
I receive the error:

```
'or' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to (Entry).
```

Comment: Please provide more information. I have recreated similar test and it compiles and gets executed correctly. The only thing I've noticed is IntelliJ IDEA's introspection warning over `|` - IDEA treats Spock test file as a regular Groovy file and it complains about applying OR operator to incompatible types. But it does not mean anything in this case. Do you get any compilation error or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a constructor in the table?

```
where:
from          | to            | result
1508446800000 | 1509483600000 | new Entry(1506805200000L, 1512075600000L)
```

Comment: Don't really help, there's the same error after I changed it.

Comment: What, it says `'or' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to (Entry).`?

Comment: Can you post all of the exception / more code? There is no `or` in the code you posted.

Comment: IDEA thinks that | is a bitwise or operation.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to replace

```
from          | to            | result
1508446800000 | 1509483600000 | new Entry(1506805200000L, 1512075600000L)
```

with

```
from          | to            || result
1508446800000 | 1509483600000 || new Entry(1506805200000L, 1512075600000L)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be needed